# trouble connecting to oracle db through ojdbc

Tags: java, oracle, jdbc, ide, intellij-idea

For those who are willing to read a bit, (skip to end for short version):

I am trying to connect my java app to a remote oracle database. with no luck I am using Mac 10.7.5 with IntelliJ Idea 12, java version "1.6.0_51" 64-bit. I have been trying to get this work all day with no success. I also was not able to use the 'DataSource' view in IntelliJ because of a missing shared dylib missing in java.library.path. I suspect the two issues are related.

I tried installing Oracle Instant Client 64-bit (including the jdbc files), copied the dylibs to /usr/lib/java and this got me close to solving the "DataSource" view issue with a different error:

```
    java.lang.RuntimeException: java.rmi.UnmarshalException: Error unmarshaling return header; nested exception is: 
    java.io.EOFException
    in RemoteUtil$RemoteInvocationHandler.invoke(RemoteUtil.java:219)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy115.connect(Unknown Source)
    in LocalDataSource.getConnection(LocalDataSource.java:158)
Caused by: java.rmi.UnmarshalException: Error unmarshaling return header; nested exception is: 
    java.io.EOFException
    at sun.rmi.transport.StreamRemoteCall.executeCall(StreamRemoteCall.java:209)
    at sun.rmi.server.UnicastRef.invoke(UnicastRef.java:142)
    at java.rmi.server.RemoteObjectInvocationHandler.invokeRemoteMethod(RemoteObjectInvocationHandler.java:178)
    at java.rmi.server.RemoteObjectInvocationHandler.invoke(RemoteObjectInvocationHandler.java:132)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy114.connect(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    in RemoteUtil$RemoteInvocationHandler.invoke(RemoteUtil.java:211)
    ... 21 more
Caused by: java.io.EOFException
    at java.io.DataInputStream.readByte(DataInputStream.java:250)
    at sun.rmi.transport.StreamRemoteCall.executeCal
```

So the journey continued and I tried using the 32bit version of the ojdbc .dylibs and .jars but then I ran into 'wrong architecture'when trying to connect to oracle db using IntelliJ's DataSource view.

I would like to keep everything consistent by using 32-bit since most of my apps use libraries that require 32-bit JVM.

tl;dr 'ers:

-Cannot connect to oracle db through IntelliJ Idea 12 DataSource view nor connect through java app using JDBC

-BackGround Info: Mac OSX 10.7.5, Java 1.6.0_51 64-bit, IntelliJ Idea 12, Remote Oracle 11G DB

-Tried both 32-bit and 64-bit versions of Oracle Instant Client with jdbc files, no luck

Any suggestions will be greatly appreciated!
Thank you

Additional Notes: I cannot connect through sqlplus either; i get the error ORA-21561: OID generation failed. Search results only point to fixing the /etc/hosts file which does not make sense for me since the db server is on a remote server and I am connecting using a TNS entry in /etc/tnsnames.ora

===UPDATE 1===
I made some progress on connecting through the java code. Using this code:

```
Class.forName("oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver").newInstance();
Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:oracle:thin:@hostname:port/service_name", "user", "password");
```

but received the error:

```
java.sql.SQLRecoverableException: IO Error: The Network Adapter could not establish the connection
```

I CAN connect using this exact piece of code on my work machine through eclipse ide but not on my Mac laptop.

Comment: The error you posted doesn't seem to have anything to do with Oracle. It looks like you'd got the Oralce part working and had hit a completely different error in another part of your code.

Comment: the error i posted seems to be related to the unstable 64-bit ojdbc .dylib files. I would like to stick to 32-bit but i get the error 'mach-o, but wrong architecture' when i try using 32-bit ojdbc libraries and jars

Comment: try jdbc:oracle:thin:@hostname:port:sid or jdbc:oracle:thin:@//host:port/serviceName and remember to have ONLY the thin driver in your classpath

Comment: just be sure to have conectivity to that ip/port at least trying it with telnet

Comment: telnet the db server and port works, i tried the different connect strings to no avail. I can connect to a db server i have installed on my work machine but cannot connect to db servers elsewhere. This may be a proxy issue...

Comment: Or a hostname resolution issue, from the OID error. Is the hostname in your connect string, and in the `tnsnames.ora`, fully qualified; and it the hostname resolvable to the (correct) IP address?

Comment: the hostname is fully qualified using hostname.domain.com.. i can ping the hostname and try to ssh into it with denial (no access to the box). the command i tried:  sqlplus 'username/password@hostname.domain.com:port:service_name' and '../service_name' but i get ORA-12154: TNS:could not resolve the connect identifier specified

Comment: @MosNo - that isn't using `tnsnames.ora`, but that Easy Connect syntax is almost right - not sure if you really have quotes in it? You can try `sqlplus username/password@//hostname.domain.com:port/service_name`, though the `//` should be optional.

Comment: i tried the above suggestion Alex but I am receiving 'Connection failed because target host or object does not exist'. I can telnet the target host at the same port; i can connect to my dev db on my work station just fine with the same structured line. When i try connecting through java with jdbc:oracle:oci with the same credentials and hostname:port i get the same error. however if i use jdbc:oracle:thin then i receive a ' IO Error: The Network Adapter could not establish the connection'..

Answer (score 0):

I can only encourage you to use the oracle thin jdbc client. There must be a very specific reason not to. With that you will likely have NO problems.

Comment: Using the thin driver doesnt make a difference since I get a nullpointerexception at DriverManager.getConnection(...) when the same code works on my desktop at work

Comment: It can make a difference, show the code where  you get the connection

Answer (score 0):

For Intellij/DataGrip 2018 DB connection via TNS I got

`[08006][17002] IO Error: Invalid connection string format, a valid format is: "host:port:sid"`

I find the problem in Oracle driver version: 11.2.0.4

I get "Test Connection > Succesful" using version **12.1.0.2**